# How to merge rows in MySQL database with 2 identical identifiers and 2 unique identifiers either using PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so this is my first question and I really have no idea how to ask it so I'm going to try and be as specific as possible. My website is an online game and for user inventories when it inserts a new item into the database

```
Table name "inventory" 
Column names "inv_id", "inv_itemid", "inv_userid", "inv_qty"
```

and  it does not add to the column `inv_qty` and populate properly instead it creates a new inv_id identifier and row for each item. I was wondering if there was a way for me to create a merge function via php to merge all items with the same inv_itemid and inv_userid while adding to the inv_qty colum and populating the inv_id

In my `inventory.php` file the `inv_id` column is used to let the user either equip the item or use it as the main variable.

I have seen this done and have tried many times and I just can't get it to work.

Comment: can you please display some sample code ? the table you're inserting to, and the php function that generates that query ?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

If it were a single key to check then you could have used 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' of mysql like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, field3, ..)
 VALUES (val1, val2, val3, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE field3='*'
```

But in your case there is a combination to consider.
If "inv_id", "inv_itemid", "inv_userid" mathces then UPDATE, otherwise INSERT.

One way to achieve this using only mysql in a single query is to create & use a Stored Procedure.

But using php you can achieve this in 2 query. First query is to determine if the combination exists. Then based on this run the next Insert or Update query.
Please check the following example:

```
$sql1 = SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE inv_id='$inv_id', inv_itemid='$inv_itemid', inv_userid='$inv_userid'
// Execute $sql1 and get the result.
```

IF result empty, then INSERT:

```
$sql2 = INSERT INTO inventory ....
```

otherwise UPDATE.

```
$sql2 = UPDATE inventory SET inv_qty=(inv_qty + $update_qty) WHERE inv_id='$inv_id', inv_itemid='$inv_itemid', inv_userid='$inv_userid'
```

Comment: `$inv=$db->query("SELECT iv.*,i.*,it.* FROM inventory iv LEFT JOIN items i ON iv.inv_itemid=i.itmid LEFT JOIN itemtypes it ON i.itmtype=it.itmtypeid WHERE iv.inv_userid={$userid} ORDER BY i.itmtype ASC, i.itmname ASC");
`
That is the query to display in inventory.php

Comment: `'equip_ring.php?ID={$i['inv_id']}`

Is how everything everything links out of inventory

Comment: The inv_id can be absolutely anything as long as it isn't a duplicate
Would there be a way to write a php function at the top of the inventory page for my users to click to merge them

Comment: @ChristianMacDonald please check my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

About:

> Would there be a way to write a php function at the top of the inventory page for my users to click to merge them

Please check with the following php function.

By calling with param: UserID, it will create a new entry with sum of the inv_qty, for each (inv_itemid + inv_userid) combination and removes the previous duplicate entries of (inv_itemid + inv_userid) leaving the newly enterd: (inv_itemid + inv_userid + (SUM of inv_qty)).

**Important, please keep a back up of the DB Table Data before running the function.**

**Please check the comments in the function and update where necessary based on your system,** Like getting the last inserted inv_id.

```
function merger_fnc($user_id) {
    // For Each Combination of: inv_itemid + inv_userid
    // This function will Insert a new row in the inventory with the SUM of inv_qty 
    // And then will remove the previous single rows of: inv_itemid + inv_userid + inv_qty

    // First get the distinct Items of the User(by UserID);
    $inv_itemids = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(inv_itemid) FROM inventory WHERE inv_userid=".$user_id);
    // Here $inv_itemids will hold all the distinct ItemIDs for the UserID;

    foreach ($inv_itemids as $inv_item) {
        // We will Insert A new row which will have the sum of 'inv_qty' for the inv_userid & inv_itemid;
        $inv_itemid = $inv_item['inv_itemid'];
        // I am not sure what type of result set your $db->query(...) returns. So I assumed it is associative array. 
        // If the result is an Array of objects, then please use: $inv_itemid = $inv_item->inv_itemid;

        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (inv_itemid, inv_userid, inv_qty) VALUES ('".$inv_itemid."', '".$user_id."', (SELECT SUM(inv_qty) FROM FROM inventory WHERE inv_userid=".$user_id."))";
        $inv_itemids = $db->query($insert_sql);

        $inserted_new_inventory_id = $db->insert_id;
        // Please check the appropriate method for it in your $db class here.
        // In mysqli, it is: mysqli_insert_id($db_conn); In PDO it is: $db_conn->lastInsertId();

        // Last we remove the previous data of combination(inv_userid & inv_itemid) but leaving our last inserted row.
        $delete_sql = "DELETE FROM inventory WHERE inv_id!='".$inserted_new_inventory_id."' AND inv_userid='".$user_id."' AND inv_itemid='".$inv_itemid."'";
        $db->query($delete_sql);
    }
}
```

If getting the last inserted inv_id is troublesome from $db(like inv_id is not defined as key in the table), you can try another approach:

Do another query and save the previous inv_id in an array, before the insertion.
After the insertion of the new entry with sum of qty, run a delete query to delete the previous single qty entries, like the following:

```
DELETE FROM inventory WHERE inv_id IN (3, 4, 7,...)
```

- Here (3, 4, 7,...) are the previous inv_id for (inv_itemid + inv_userid) combination.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help when adding into the inventory page it kills the whole page because of how it is written is there anyway to make it a seperate page they click that merges them? Like for example 

Merge.php when they navigate to that page it does the merge function I tried to do it but I couldn't get it to Merge it just showed a blank page

Comment: This type of processes(merge, cleanup) are usually not put in front site. If anthing goes wrong, errors it will impact the sites audience. Usually this sort of things are managed with scheduled tasks like cron jobs or atleast in the site's admin panel, where an admin can run these sort of tasks. I actually do not know anything about your project's structure. I would suggest you create a page or panel in your site's admin panel, where you can use the DB cleanup function for the users of the site :)